# Querying ignoring a time portion of TIMESTAMP fields along with JPA converter

Tags: hibernate, jpa

A property in an entity named `Discount` is declared as follows.

```
@Column(name = "discount_start_date")
private LocalDateTime discountStartDate; // Getter & setter.
```

It is type of `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL. I need somewhere to search a list of rows based on the date portion of the given field `discount_start_date` ignoring the time portion of that field (it is just an example).

**The conversion from `java.time.LocalDateTime` to `java.sql.Timestamp` and vice verse is transparently handled by a JPA (2.1) converter.**

The following attempt will certainly fail.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("25-Feb-2016 00:52:33 AM +0000", formatter); // This is submitted by clients.

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
calendar.setTime(Date.from(dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));

TypedQuery<Discount> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Discount d WHERE d.discountStartDate >= :param", Discount.class);
List<Discount> list = query.setParameter("param", calendar, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

The query fails with the following exception.

```
00:15:06,546 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-48) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component DiscountBean for method public abstract java.lang.Long admin.services.DiscountService.test(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1456361553000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=9,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=25,DAY_OF_YEAR=56,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=52,SECOND=33,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (DATE)]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at admin.services.DiscountService$$$view28.test(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at admin.beans.DiscountService$1766907887$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.test(Unknown Source)
    at admin.bean.DiscountManagedBean.load(DiscountManagedBean.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:973)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
00:15:06,750 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-48) Error Rendering View[/admin/Discount.xhtml]: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1456361553000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=9,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=25,DAY_OF_YEAR=56,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=52,SECOND=33,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (DATE)]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at admin.services.DiscountService$$$view28.test(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at admin.beans.DiscountService$1766907887$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.test(Unknown Source)
    at admin.bean.DiscountManagedBean.load(DiscountManagedBean.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:973)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:128)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:33)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1456361553000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=9,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=25,DAY_OF_YEAR=56,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=52,SECOND=33,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (DATE)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:897)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$100(QueryImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:656)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32)
    at admin.beans.DiscountBean.test1(DiscountBean.java:61)
    at admin.beans.DiscountBean.test(DiscountBean.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at service.ejb.interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.handle(ExceptionInterceptor.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 128 more
```

---

The corresponding equivalent attempt using the JPA criteria API will fail to compile for the obvious reason.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("25-Feb-2016 00:52:33 AM +0000", formatter); // This is submitted by clients.

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
calendar.setTime(Date.from(dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));

Parameter<Calendar> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Calendar.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Discount_.discountStartDate), parameter));
List<Discount> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameter, calendar, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

The second last line will not compile because `Discount_.discountStartDate` points to `SingularAttribute<Discount, LocalDateTime>` which does not match with `Parameter<Calendar>` as a parameter to `greaterThanOrEqualTo()`.

What is the way to go for fetching results based on only the date portion of `TIMESTAMP` type fields?

It may work with fields designated with `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` in the target entity itself but it requires changes depriving us of flexibility to use a standard JPA converter with `autoApply` set to `true`.

---

The `TypedQuery<X>` interface has no overloaded `setParameter()` method as of now accepting a parameter of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from the JavaTime API of Java SE 8 for the obvious reason.

```
public <T extends Object> TypedQuery<X> setParameter(Parameter<T> param, T value);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(Parameter<Calendar> param, Calendar value, TemporalType temporalType);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(Parameter<Date> param, Date value, TemporalType temporalType);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(String name, Object value);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(String name, Calendar value, TemporalType temporalType);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(String name, Date value, TemporalType temporalType);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(int position, Object value);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(int position, Calendar value, TemporalType temporalType);
public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(int position, Date value, TemporalType temporalType);
```

So, no workaround until the next release of JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to use [`Expression.as()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as-java.lang.Class-)

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Discount> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Discount.class);
Root<Discount> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Discount.class));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("25-Feb-2016 00:52:33 AM +0000", formatter);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
calendar.setTime(Date.from(dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));

ParameterExpression<Calendar> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Calendar.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Discount_.discountStartDate).as(Calendar.class), parameter));
List<Discount> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameter, calendar, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

Notice `.as(Calendar.class)` in the `WHERE` clause of the query. It generates the following SQL query.

```sql
select
    discount0_.`discount_id` as discount1_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_code` as discount2_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_end_date` as discount3_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_percent` as discount4_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_start_date` as discount5_12_,
    discount0_.`row_version` as row_vers6_12_ 
from
    `jboss_projectdb`.`discount` discount0_ 
where
    cast(discount0_.`discount_start_date` as datetime)>=?
```

Notice that the Hibernate provider casts the column to `datetime` - `cast(discount0_.discount_start_date as datetime)` which is not of our interest.

We want either

```sql
cast(discount0_.`discount_start_date` as date)
```

or

```sql
date(discount0_.`discount_start_date`)
```

---

Two of the possible approaches.

Deal with [`CriteriaBuilder.function()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-) as follows.

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Discount> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Discount.class);
Root<Discount> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Discount.class));

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
Date date = dateFormat.parse("25-Feb-2016 00:52:33 AM +0000");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
calendar.setTime(date);

Expression<Calendar> function = criteriaBuilder.function("date", Calendar.class, root.get(Discount_.discountStartDate));
ParameterExpression<Calendar> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Calendar.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(function, parameter));
List<Discount> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameter, calendar, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

It produces the following SQL statement.

```sql
select
    discount0_.`discount_id` as discount1_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_code` as discount2_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_end_date` as discount3_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_percent` as discount4_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_start_date` as discount5_12_,
    discount0_.`row_version` as row_vers6_12_ 
from
    `jboss_projectdb`.`discount` discount0_ 
where
    date(discount0_.`discount_start_date`)>=?
```

The above approach is however, slightly coupled with the underlying database function `date()` being embedded in the criteria query itself thus, affecting portability a little.

A more viable approach would thus be to use `.as(java.sql.Date.class)` as follows.

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Discount> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Discount.class);
Root<Discount> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Discount.class));

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
Date date = dateFormat.parse("25-Feb-2016 00:52:33 AM +0000");

ParameterExpression<Date> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Discount_.discountStartDate).as(java.sql.Date.class), parameter));
List<Discount> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameter, date, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

This is fully portable across different RDBMS. It generates the following SQL query.

```sql
select
    discount0_.`discount_id` as discount1_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_code` as discount2_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_end_date` as discount3_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_percent` as discount4_12_,
    discount0_.`discount_start_date` as discount5_12_,
    discount0_.`row_version` as row_vers6_12_ 
from
    `jboss_projectdb`.`discount` discount0_ 
where
    cast(discount0_.`discount_start_date` as date)>=?
```

---

There is a caution in the Java docs about [`Expression.as()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as-java.lang.Class-).

> Perform a typecast upon the expression, returning a new expression
>   object. This method does not cause type conversion: the runtime type
>   is not changed. **Warning: may result in a runtime failure.**

This is however, not going to affect in this particular case as we know what type we are expecting it to cast to.

---

Switching between `java.time.LocalDateTime` / `java.time.ZonedDateTime` and `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` is a story apart. Therefore, that part has been excluded completely from this answer for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

CriteriaBuilder has date conversion functions: Ref: [how to find by date from timestamp column in JPA criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716586/how-to-find-by-date-from-timestamp-column-in-jpa-criteria). You can use those to build a predicate:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Discount> q = cb.createQuery(Discount.class);
Root<Discount> d = q.from(Discount.class);
// split up localdatetime field.
Path<LocalDateTime> ldt = d.<LocalDateTime>get("localDataTime");
Expression<Integer> dbYear = cb.function("year", Integer.class, ldt);
Expression<Integer> dbMonth = cb.function("month", Integer.class, ldt);
Expression<Integer> dbDay = cb.function("day", Integer.class, ldt);
// build query
q.select(d).where(cb.equal(dbYear, 2016), cb.equal(dbMonth, 3), cb.equal(dbDay, 11));
Discount r = em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(r);
```

This will result in the following SQL:

```
select 
    discount0_.id as id1_0_, 
    discount0_.localDataTime as localDat2_0_ 
from 
    Discount discount0_ 
where 
    extract(year from discount0_.localDataTime)=2016 
    and extract(month from discount0_.localDataTime)=3 
    and extract(day from discount0_.localDataTime)=11
```

Comment: Using [`Expression#as()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as-java.lang.Class-) like this `criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Discount_.discountStartDate).as(Calendar.class), parameter)` (notice `.as(Calendar.class)`) compiles and works but it generates `where cast(discount0_.discount_start_date as datetime)>=?` (for MySQL) where `where cast(discount0_.discount_start_date as date)>=?` is expected. I am till exploring it hoping that it would work.

Comment: A calendar is a datetime object, isn't it?